# Quarkus - integration tests and docker image both reading only 29 bytes of key file, while unit test reading 32 bytes

Tags: java, docker, jwt, quarkus, secret-key

I encountered some weird problem while reading a secret key file in Quarkus/Docker only getting 29 bytes while in unit test I got 32 bytes. That causes unit tests passing but integration tests not passing and local docker image running failing.

The exception shown in the log is: (from nimbusds.jose, not directly from Quarkus)

```java
Caused by: com.nimbusds.jose.JOSEException: AES/GCM/NoPadding decryption failed: Tag mismatch!
    at com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.impl.AESGCM.decrypt(AESGCM.java:301)
    at com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.impl.ContentCryptoProvider.decrypt(ContentCryptoProvider.java:279)
    at com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.DirectDecrypter.decrypt(DirectDecrypter.java:271)
    at com.nimbusds.jose.JWEObject.decrypt(JWEObject.java:415)
    at com.org.TokenParser.parseToken(TokenParser.java:38)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decryptFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:623)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1116)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1053)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:853)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2202)
    at com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.impl.AESGCM.decrypt(AESGCM.java:297)
```

I suspect the mismatch of size of key caused this problem, as 32 bytes are needed for a 256 bits key but only 29 bytes are found.

In short, I need to activate a key file and decrypt a JWT token. In local unit/int test, I use a file under `src/test/resource`; in prod, there is a file loaded into a data volume in Openshift. In the code I first try to find the file under `/opt/data/environment`; if not found, fallback to `src/test/resources`. The application deployed in cloud is fine(reading 32 bytes and no exception), problem is in local.

The related code:
JWT decryption:

```java
import com.nimbusds.jose.JWEDecrypter;
import com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.factories.DefaultJWEDecrypterFactory;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.EncryptedJWT;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.JWTClaimsSet;
...
EncryptedJWT jwt = EncryptedJWT.parse(token);
DefaultJWEDecrypterFactory factory = new DefaultJWEDecrypterFactory();
JWEDecrypter decrypter = factory.createJWEDecrypter(jwt.getHeader(), this.secretKey);
jwt.decrypt(decrypter); // <<<<<< here padding error
```

Creating secretKey:

```java
SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(data,"AES");
```

Reading key data:

```java
InputStream keyFileStream = TokenHandler.class.getResourceAsStream("/key.shared"); // reading from src/main/resources
keyFileBytes = readKeyFromInputStream(keyFileStream);
...
```

and

```java
    static byte[] readKeyFromInputStream(final InputStream sharedKeyStream) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        byte[] keyBytes;
        if (sharedKeyStream == null) {
            keyBytes = autoGenerateKey();
        } else {
            keyBytes = new byte[sharedKeyStream.available()]; // 32 bytes available
            // Only 29 bytes will be read if using "read(keyBytes)", must read explicitly till 32 bytes
            int count = sharedKeyStream.read(keyBytes, 0, 32);
            LOG.infof("Activating security token handler with key from input stream (length = %d bytes)", count);
            //if (count != 32) {
            //    throw new IOException("Key read bytes length does not match expected number(32), cannot initialize key!");
            //}
        }
        return keyBytes;
    }
```

Unit test that passes:

```java
    @Test
    void shouldRead32BytesFromInputStream() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        // given
        InputStream keyFileStream = TokenHandlerTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/key.shared");

        // when
        byte[] keyFileBytes = TokenHandler.readKeyFromInputStream(keyFileStream);

        // then
        assertEquals(32, keyFileBytes.length);
    }
```

Even I read 32 bytes explicitly, I cannot eliminate the original exception, as in int test, only 29 bytes found.

Of course, in Quarkus int test, the application jar is used, where the key is packaged into. I think that file in jar is used; but even checking the file size in jar, it's still 32 bytes. I don't know where the 29 bytes coming from.

So:

- is my original exception related to key length difference?
- how to solve it in integration test so that I still load local file but got 32 bytes?

The file has 32 bytes, as shown by Gnome Files manager and `wc -c`. I am working on Linux, Docker container is also based on Linux, where also only 29 bytes are read in `docker run`.

---

AND: if I put the same file under `src/jib/opt/data/environment`, jib maven plugin will include that file into the docker image, and image running is fine now. So why???

---

Another update: if I replace the key file with a file with exact 32 bytes of text, 32 bytes are read, and the integration test works. So there is something wrong with this key file that got compressed while creating jar, which is not compressed when key file is plain text file?? The text key file is:

```
long-secret-key-for-256-bits-key
```

The original key file: (got from `od`)

```
��Y"dpq����n��b�v"G:�/����_���
```

In hex:

```
$ od -t x1 key.shared
0000000 xx ec ba 59 22 64 70 71 d6 f7 xx 8f 6e f1 f8 xx
0000020 xx 76 22 47 3a xx 2f bd e6 95 d9 5f dd f6 xx e9
0000040
```

(some part hidden with `xx`)

That could be because the original key file is used everywhere, but I am the first one doing integration test like this in my team; maybe it has always been loaded directly as data volume, not in a jar.

Comment: Maybe the way I use AES key is not correct... now when I think of it, `SecretKeySpec` does not check key type and is only used for DES key...